# How to pass value from subclass to super class during initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, inheritance, superclass

Suppose, I've two view controller. ViewController1 is the sub class of ViewController2. From subclass (ViewController1), I called superclass init method & passed a value by parameter & assigned that value to the superclass variable. But In superclass (ViewController2)'s viewDidLoad method, that value is always null. Why ? How can I pass that value from sub to super so that I can get that value in super class's viewDidLoad method ?

ViewController1.h

```
@interface ViewController : ViewController2

@end
```

ViewController1.m

```
@implementation ViewController

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super initWithName:@"Hello"];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"1  :");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

ViewController2.h

```
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
-(instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name;

@end
```

ViewController2.m

```
- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.name = name;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSLog(@"2  : %@", self.name);

}

@end
```

Comment: This should work. I suspect your issue is somewhere else. Can you also log  the adresse of your object and add the output to your question ?

Comment: The output is just null like -  "2016-03-15 14:37:52.651 dfsdfd[2717:54086] 2  : (null)"

Comment: If your need is just to hold the value of name, why dont you just set it where it needs like 
self.name = @"asd";

Comment: I also created a new project & implemented same thing again, but the result is same.

Comment: You are you creating the viewcontroller1 instance?

Comment: How do you create ViewController instance? If you are not using init method, it won't be called. Maybe it's being created by a storyboard?

Comment: Have you tried checking for the variable **after** `viewDidLoad` is called?

Comment: call [super someMethodWithSomeVariable:variable] or create property in a superclass and assign it before [super viewDidLoad]

Comment: Does the following LOC get executed?

NSLog(@"1  :");

I think that's the cause.

Comment: and probably you initiate UIViewController from storyboadrd so -initWithCoder is executed instead of -init

Comment: Yes i've only one viewcontroller in storyboard that is ViewController1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tired your code and it worked just fine. I suspect, that you don't instantiate your ViewController directly. Do you use storyboard in your project? If yes - you should override `initWithCoder:` in ViewController.

However, it is bad idea to set any properties of view controllers during `init`-family methods. According to Apple recommendations, all customisation should be done in `-viewDidLoad` or `-viewWill`/`DidAppear` methods.

If you absolutely in need to set `name` property from outside, it is better you assign it directly, not trough passing argument to `init` method.

One more thing - `initWithNibName:bundle:` is *Designated initializer*. It means, that your subclasses absolutely must in the end call it during initialisation chain.

Comment: Ya i think it's the problem. I have a stroryboard with ViewController1.

Comment: Can you tell me if i avoid init family method then how can i set the super class variable (name) from the sub class ? Actually i need this mechanism for one of my existence project. The subclass is a storyboard class & i need to pass a value from subclass to super class.

Comment: Subclasses have access to superclasses properties. So, it is simple. In `viewDidLoad` of ViewController place this `self.name = @"Hello";`

Comment: No, it's not working. In ViewController, -     - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   
    self.name = @"Hello";
    
}  In ViewController2 , (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
  
    
    NSLog(@"2  : %@", self.name);//This is still null
    
}

Comment: No, it should be `-(void) viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad]; self.name = @"Hello"; NSLog(@"2 : %@", self.name); }

Comment: In sub class i set the super class property in viewdidload as self.name = @"Hello" & in super class i logged that property in viewdidload but it shows null

Comment: Of course it is - you set property after `[super viewDidLoad]` where NSLog is executed. You can do this
`- (void) viewDidLoad { self.name = @"Hello"; [super viewDidLoad]; }

Comment: Yaa got the point. I have missed this simple thing. Thanks. It's working.

Comment: Glad I could help you =)

Answer (score 0):

Updated - 16-Mar-2016

Example :

ViewController1.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController1 : ViewController2

@end
```

ViewController1.m

```
#import "ViewController1.h"

@interface ViewController1 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController1

-(instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    //self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil andUserName:@"Ramesh Annadurai"];

    // we can use above init method or below method, both will work

    self = [super initWithName:@"Test Name"];

    if (self) {

        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];

    }

    return self;
}

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
//self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

// If you are using storyboard use this initWithCoder method.

    self = [super initWithName:@"Test Name"];

    if (self) {

    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

ViewController2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil andUserName:(NSString *) userName;

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *) userName;

@end
```

ViewController2.m

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *userName;

@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil andUserName:(NSString *) userName
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {

        self.userName = userName;

    }

    return self;

}

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *) userName
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    if (self) {

        self.userName = userName;

    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"User Name : %@", self.userName);

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

Comment: It won't help. Just try this code. After all - init is method that initialises and returns `instancetype` object no matter what.

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr `init` *creates* the instance?  Are you sure?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, my bad. Thanks for comment

Comment: @Nawnit That is exactly the issue - you're not using storyboard. Author's approach works without storyboard too. But he uses storyboard, so problems lies not in calling right `init` methods